# Concatenar cada 9 linhas com espaço como delimitador

Tags: python-3.x, awk

Tenho um ficheiro de texto com cerca de 40000 e preciso agrupar numa linha só cada 9 linhas do meu txt.

Eis como tenho as linhas

```py
ACH-CHT
19394
4462
71%
148
147
28
74000
147000
```

e como preciso que fique

```
ACH-CHT 19394 4462 71% 148 147 28 74000 147000
```

Tenho feito a junção com awk, mas gostava se possivel que ficasse tudo em python

```
awk "{ ORS = (NR%9 ? FS : RS) } 1" "D:\AM4v2\Completos\ZRH_ORIG_temp3.txt" > "D:\AM4v2\Completos\ZRH.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

```
def get_lines(filepath, separator='\t'):
    with open(filepath, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        args = [iter(f)] * 9
        for group in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=''):
            yield separator.join(g.rstrip('\n') for g in group)
```

<sup>[Exemplo do código rodando no Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-543581-6333)</sup>

---

## Explicação

Estou adaptando o código mostrado na [seção de receitas da documentação do módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (função `grouper` com `incomplete='fill'`).

No meu código crio uma lista com 9 referências ao mesmo iterador (o iterador do arquivo que me retorna uma linha por vez) e depois uso a função [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) do mesmo módulo para consumir o iterador do do arquivo de 9 em 9 linhas.

Com isso minha variável `group` conterá uma tupla com o conteúdo das linhas lidas. Ex.:

```py
('linha1\n', 'linha2\n', 'linha3\n', ..., 'linha9\n')
```

Agora basta remover os `\n` e concatenar em uma linha só usando:

```
yield separator.join(g.rstrip('\n') for g in group)
```

Como estamos usando *generators* para ler cada linha somente quando necessário, não carregamos todo o arquivo e memória podendo ler arquivos grandes sem se preocupar com a RAM. Basta consumir o novo generator, exemplo:

```
for line in get_lines('data.txt'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Obrigado Fernado, era mesmo isto que precisava :)

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda do @fernandosavio consegui resolver (na verdade só foi preciso acrecentar uma quebra de linha a string criada.)

Eis como ficou:

```
def get_lines(filepath, separator='\t'):
with open(filepath, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    args = [iter(f)] * 9
    for group in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=''):
        yield separator.join(g.rstrip('\n') for g in group)

with open("ficheiro_tratado.txt","w") as outfile4:
    for line in get_lines(outfile2, separator= " "):
        line=(line + "\n" )
        outfile4.write(line)
```